# Python BeautifulSoup - Scraping Google Finance historical data

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrap Google Finance historical data. I was need of to total number of rows, which is located along with the pagination. The following is the div tag which is responsible for displaying the total number of rows:

```
<div class="tpsd">1 - 30 of 1634 rows</div>
```

I tried using the following code to get the data, but its returning an empty list:

```
soup.find_all('div', 'tpsd')
```

I tried getting the entire table but even then I was not successful, when I checked the page source I was able to find the value inside a JavaScript function. When I Googled how to get values from script tag, it was mentioned to used regex. So, I tried using regex and the following is my code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=13564339&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Aug+18%2C+2016&num=30&ei=ilC1V6HlPIasuASP9Y7gAQ')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
var = soup.find_all("script")[8].string
a = re.compile('google.finance.applyPagination\((.*)\'http', re.DOTALL)
b =  a.search(var)
num = b.group(1)
print(num.replace(',','').split('\n')[3])
```

I am able to get the values which I want, but my doubt is whether the above code which I used to get the values is correct, or is there any other way better way. Kindly help.

Comment: What does  *doubt is whether the above code which I used to get the values is correct* mean? Does it give you what you need?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes.. I am getting the values which I want from the script tag. But I am not getting the values by using the div tag. Is there any way to get the values using div tag?

Comment: If you want to parse the page as you see it in your browser you will need something like selenium that can run Javascript, are you trying to parse the table or what exactly?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No I am try to get the total number of rows, which is located near the pagination. I thought there might be some way to get the values from div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pass an offset i.e *start=..* to the url getting 30 rows at a time which is exactly what is happening with the pagination logic:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=13564339&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&" \
      "enddate=Aug+18%2C+2016&num=30&ei=ilC1V6HlPIasuASP9Y7gAQ&start={}"


with requests.session() as s:
    start = 0
    req = s.get(url.format(start))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
    all_rows = table.find_all("tr")
    while True:
        start += 30
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url.format(start)).content, "lxml")
        table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
        if not table:
            break
        all_rows.extend(table.find_all("tr"))
```

You can also get the total rows using the script tag and use that with range:

```
with requests.session() as s:
    req = s.get(url.format(0))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
    scr = soup.find("script", text=re.compile('google.finance.applyPagination'))
    total = int(scr.text.split(",", 3)[2])
    all_rows = table.find_all("tr")

    for start in range(30, total+1, 30):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url.format(start)).content, "lxml")
        table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
        all_rows.extend(table.find_all("tr"))
print(len(all_rows))
```

The `num=30` is the amount of rows per page, to make less requests you can set it to 200 which seems to be the max and work your step/offset from that.

```
url = "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=13564339&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&" \
      "enddate=Aug+18%2C+2016&num=200&ei=ilC1V6HlPIasuASP9Y7gAQ&start={}"


with requests.session() as s:
    req = s.get(url.format(0))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
    scr = soup.find("script", text=re.compile('google.finance.applyPagination'))
    total = int(scr.text.split(",", 3)[2])
    all_rows = table.find_all("tr")
    for start in range(200, total+1, 200):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url.format(start)).content, "lxml")
        print(url.format(start)
        table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
        all_rows.extend(table.find_all("tr"))
```

If we run the code, you will see we get 1643 rows:

```
In [7]: with requests.session() as s:
   ...:         req = s.get(url.format(0))
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
   ...:         table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
   ...:         scr = soup.find("script", text=re.compile('google.finance.applyPagination'))
   ...:         total = int(scr.text.split(",", 3)[2])
   ...:         all_rows = table.find_all("tr")
   ...:         for start in range(200, total+1, 200):
   ...:                 soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url.format(start)).content, "lxml")
   ...:                 table = soup.select_one("table.gf-table.historical_price")
   ...:                 all_rows.extend(table.find_all("tr"))
   ...:         print(len(all_rows))
   ...:         

1643

In [8]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the python module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance

The api is simple:

```
#The google finance API that we need.
from googlefinance import getQuotes
#The json handeler, since the API returns a JSON.
import json


intelJSON = (getQuotes('INTC'))

intelDump = json.dumps(intelJSON, indent=2)

intelInfo = json.loads(intelDump)

intelPrice = intelInfo[0]['LastTradePrice']
intelTime  = intelInfo[0]['LastTradeDateTimeLong']

print ("As of " + intelTime  + ", Intel stock is trading at: " + intelPrice)
```

Comment: Will I be able to get the historical data also?

Comment: In there GitHub page it was mentioned as follows: "This module provides no delay, real time stock data in NYSE & NASDAQ." I guess it dont get historical data.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rich

Answer (score 0):

I prefer having all the raw CSV files that are available for download from Google Finance. I wrote a quick python script to automatically download all the historical price info for a list of companies -- it's equivalent to how a human might use the "Download to Spreadsheet" link manually. [image: Download to Spreadsheet link on Google Finance historical prices page for a company]

Here's the GitHub repo, with the downloaded CSV files for all S&P 500 stocks (in the rawCSV folder): https://github.com/liezl200/stockScraper

It uses this link [http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=googl&startdate=May+3%2C+2012&enddate=Apr+30%2C+2017&output=csv](http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=googl&startdate=May%203%2C%202012&enddate=Apr%2030%2C%202017&num=30&output=csv) where the key here is the last output parameter, `output=csv`. I use `urllib.urlretrieve(download_url, local_csv_filename)` to retrieve the CSV.

Comment: I had this idea in mind, but whenever i wanted to update, this might take some time. Thanks for the response.